# Does SE automatically cull colourful language?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I may add an ephemeral comment which has language that could be described as colourful.
(Invariably in response to unnecessarily abrupt behaviour.)

Today I noticed that one remark was removed seconds after posting.

Is this automatic or an on-the-ball moderator?

Comment: You may be interested in my data-gathering initiative [What is the SE version of Seven Dirty Words?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835)

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat: Thank you! I needed a laugh :-).

Comment: Oh, we have plenty of colorful language: just look at all the combinatorics questions with *ahem* blue balls. :-)

Comment: At least combinatorics is somewhat discrete, continuity seems to make things worse, for example, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/90737/27978.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some colourful language needs only a single flag to get the comment removed. It may have been that. If it is the comment I think it was, that is very probably what happened.

Comment: Thanks! Will need to experiment more :-). The triggering incident happened in the last few minutes...

Comment: A good half hour ago, methinks. While I can understand your frustration in that situation, you used a word that makes one-click-deletion not entirely unreasonable. Somebody clicked.

Comment: I agree that was inappropriate. But compared to what could have come out, it was pretty mild. I went back to delete it (remorse) and it was gone...

Comment: So it was deleted a few seconds earlier. No harm done then, right?

Comment: I appreciate your concern. A few negative interactions over the last few days on a few SE sites have left me rather sensitised.